# getting the error like JSON schema is not correct. Enter specified JSON scehma.,Create an Array of Favorite fruits Object

Tags: json

0

I have the following assessment which is to Create Array of Favorite Food items object in data.json file.

The Array of Objects should have the following fields :

Name

Type

Price

After writing the JSON data, this file should be imported in loopobject.js.

I tried the above request with the below data.json

**data.json**

```
"{[{\"Name\":\"Apple\",\"Type\":\"fruit\",\"Price\":123},{\"Name\":\"pizza\",\"Type\":\"italian\",\"Price\":360},{\"Name\":\"burger\",\"Type\":\"mac&cheese\",\"Price\":321},{\"Name\":\"jangri\",\"Type\":\"sweet\",\"Price\":329}]}"
```

**loopObject.js**

```
var json = require('./data.json');

json.forEach(function(object) { console.log(object.Name); });
```

**verify.js**

```
const Joi = require('joi');
const fss =require('fs');

const schema = Joi.array().min(3).has({
    Name: Joi.string().required(),
    Type: Joi.string().required(),
    Price: Joi.number().required(),
});

var data;

try{
 data = require("./data.json");    
}catch(e)
{
 data={};
}

var XMLWriter = require('xml-writer');
    xw = new XMLWriter;


const result = Joi.validate(data, schema);




// You can also pass a callback which will be called synchronously with the validation result.
Joi.validate(data, schema, function (err, value) {
if(err==null)
{ console.log("JSON is valid.");

}else{
    console.log("JSON schema is not correct. Enter specified JSON scehma.");
}

});
```

i have tried couple of ways, everything looks good,but don't know where i am doing mistake. Could you please help on this??

Answer (score 0):

The JSON format is not correct, try this one:

**data.json**

```json
[
  {
    "Name": "someName",
    "Type": "someType",
    "Price": 123
  },
  {
    "Name": "someName",
    "Type": "someType",
    "Price": 123
  },
  {
    "Name": "someName",
    "Type": "someType",
    "Price": 123
  },
  {
    "Name": "someName",
    "Type": "someType",
    "Price": 123
  }
]
```

The JSON data describes an array, and each element of that array is an object.